# using offset with a cell

Tags: vba, excel

If I have a cell in a range of  excel, how do I use the offset function in relation to the cell?

Excel doesn't like cell.offset(-1,0) I guess because offset is only meant to be used with a range.

I have tried namedrange.cell.offset(-1,0) but that clearly isn't right.

```
Set r = range("named_range")
For Each cell In r
If IsEmpty(cell) Then

  j = j + 1
  n = 1

While IsEmpty(cell.Offset(-n, 0))
  n = n + 1
Wend
```

So my problem is the cell.offset(-n,0) part

Thank you

Comment: @urdearboy what did I do wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You are using the offset property correctly. Do you get an error? What problem are you having?

Comment: Yes I am getting an error on IsEmpty(cell.Offset(-n, 0)) - application defined error

Comment: You may have a variable missing. Show all of your code. From `Sub` to `End Sub`. I pasted your code, declared the variables, and executed with no error

Comment: What is the range you are searching? Does it start at the first row? AND is the first value in the row blank? If so that is your problem

Answer (score 0):

> Application Defined Error

The only way I could duplicate your issue is when the offset value leads to an invalid cell location. The lowest row value is `1`. I'm guessing your offset is taking you to an invalid row (`0`) which is giving you the error.

If you are at `A1` and use `Range("A1").Offset(-1, 0)`, you will get an error. There is no row above **Row 1**.

Similarly, there is no column before **Column A**. `Range("A1").Offset(0, -1) will also give produce the same error.

Comment: Thank you, my problem is that I am looping over a range. So using 'for cell in range', and then I need to offset on the cell. So how do I write the cell as a range?

Comment: I can't see where you said that. I have edited my OP with my code. Hope that is clear. Thank you